# Strategies for improving performance when using Tensorflow w / C++?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm fairly new to Tensorflow in and ML in general and am wondering what strategies I can use to increase performance of an application I am building.

My app is using the Tensorflow C++ interface, with a source compiled TF 0.11 libtensorflow_cc.so (built with  bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx and optionally adding --config=cuda) for either AVX or AVX + CUDA on Mac OS X 10.12.1, on an MacBook Pro 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7 (2 cores 8 threads) with 16GB ram and a Nvidia 750m w/ 2GB VRam)

My application is using Inception V3 model and pulling feature vectors from pool_3 layer. I'm decoding video frames via native API's and passing those in memory buffers to the C++ interface for TF and running them into a session.

I'm not currently batching, but I am caching my session and re-using it for each individual decoded frame / tensor submission. Ive noticed that both CPU and GPU performance is about the same, taking about 40 to 50 seconds to process 222 frames, which seems very slow to me. Ive confirmed CUDA is being invoked, loaded, and the GPU is functioning (or appears so).

Some questions:

- In general what should I expect for reasonable performance time wise of TF doing a frame of Inception on a consumer laptop?
- How much of a difference does batching make for these operations? For tensors of 1x299x299x3 , I imagine I am doing more PCI transfer waiting than waiting on for meaningful work from the GPU?
- if so Is there a good example of batching under C++ for InceptionV3?
- Is there operations that cause additional CPU->GPU Syncronization that might otherwise be avoided?
- Is there a way to ensure my sessions / graphs share resources ? Can I use nested scopes somehow in this manner?  I couldn't quite get that to work but likely missed something.
- Any good documentation of general strategies for things to do / avoid?

My code is below:

https://github.com/Synopsis/Synopsis/blob/TensorFlow/Synopsis/TensorFlowAnalyzer/TensorFlowAnalyzer.mm

Thank you very much

For reference, OpenCV analysis using perceptual hash, histogram, dense optical flow, sparse optical flow for point tracking, and simple saliency detection takes 4 to 5 seconds for the same 222 frames using CPU or CPU + OpenCL.

https://github.com/Synopsis/Synopsis/tree/TensorFlow/Synopsis/StandardAnalyzer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your last question first, if there's documentation about performance optimization, yes:

- The [TensorFlow Performance Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/)
- The [TensorFlow GPU profiling hints](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659)

Laptop performance is highly variable, and TF isn't particularly optimized for laptop GPUs.  The numbers you're getting (222 frames in 40-50 seconds) ~= 5 fps don't seem crazy on a laptop platform, using the 2016 version of TensorFlow, with inception.  With some of the performance improvements outlined in the performance guide above, that should probably be doubled in late 2017.

For batching, yes - the newer [example inception model code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/eval_image_classifier.py) allows a variable batch size at inference time.  This is mostly about whether the model itself was defined to handle a batch size, which is something improved since 2016.

Batching for inference will make a pretty big difference on GPU.  Whether it helps on CPU depends a lot -- for example, if you build with MKL-DNN support, batching should be considered mandatory, but basic TensorFlow may not benefit as much.